# Deleting a commit in github

Tags: github, commit

Is it possible to undo one or two faulty commits I have made to Github.  I'm not very good at coding either so if there's a way to do it without coding, that would be great.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via doing the following command in your local workspace:

```
git reset --merge <hash>
```

Where `<hash>` is the commit prior to the commits that you want to revert.

The above command is enough if you haven't pushed to GitHub.  If you have pushed to GitHub, you then run the following to force an update of the remote branch:

```
git push --force origin <branch>
```

(**Note:** This is assuming that your remote is named `origin`, but rename as appropriate.)

Note that this re-writes history on the remote branch, and is not recommended if other developers are using the same branch.  If you know who the developers are, you can communicate with them to delete their local copies of the modified branch and ask them to run `git fetch` to get a new copy of the branch.

Comment: Don't use the `--hard` flag, use `--merge` in order to avoid losing changes in working directory (either staged or unstaged).

Comment: Huh?  When do you 'git push' to GitHub... before or after 'git reset'?

Comment: @zipzit - After `git reset`.  `git reset` updates your local branch pointer to the `<hash>` commit.  `git push --force` updates the remote branch on GitHub.